# Do I have to include 是 in 你的生日(是)什么时候？

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs

I would like to know if the verb 是 (shi) is optional?

- 你的生日是什么时候？ (Ni de shengri shi shen me shi hou?)
- 你的生日什么时候？ (Ni de shengri shen me shi hou?)

Which of those two sentence used more?

Comment: jukuu's 1st 10 examples for "when is your birthday" all have ＂是＂，also note:你的生日是哪一天?

Comment: 你的生日是什么时候 is a little more formal. 你的生日什么时候 is acceptable in casual conversations.

Comment: according to e.g. "外国人实用现代汉语语法＂there are the following types of simple sentences, (1)subject-predicate 主谓句,(2)Non-S-P 非主谓句 (a)subjectless 无主句 (b)one-word 独语句 (c)elliptical 简略句。If verb ＂是＂is omitted it becomes an elliptical sentence,简略句都不能离开上下文，对话时常用简略句，简略句只能在一定的语言环境中使用，也就是说不能脱离当时环境和上下文。

Comment: I would never say `你的生日什么时候`. It's quite weird. If you really prefer this, I suggest say `你的生日什么时候啊`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*你的生日是什麼時候?*
(When is your birthday?) is the proper way to propose a question.
*你(的)生日什麼時候?* is gramatically incorrect but seldom heard when speaking for shortness

Also, 
*你(的)生日是哪一天?*
(What day is your birthday?)
and, *你什麼時候生日?*
are frequently used for asking about birthdays.

These can also be used in many other occations. For example:

- *你什麼時候出去的?* (When did you get out?)
- *你們什麼時候要走(=離開,出發)?* (When are you guys going to leave?)

These are really colloquial way to speak

I'll take the last one when speaking :-)

Comment: “你生日什麼時候？” totally makes sense for me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I must say the answer provided by user12473 is not "colloquial".

For asking the birthday, you can say 你什么时候生日, 你生日什么时候, 你什么时候过生日, 你生日在什么时候. Note that there's no use of 的 in colloquial language.

Comment: I disagree with your last sentence - who says you can't use 的 colloquially?!? Use it as much as you like! That's why it's colloquial - but otherwise this is right.

Comment: If you can read simplified Chinese I recommend this [article](http://www.yangzhiping.com/psy/wenxin02.html) to you, it introduces why we should avoid using too much "的".

Comment: I think this is about what people actually say, not what someone somewhere thinks we ought to say.

Answer (score 0):

In my ears, 你的生日什麼時候？ sounds more authentic than 你的生日是什麼時候？  Which of the phrasing is more common might depend on location though.  As a non-native speaker, one should remember that nouns or pronouns can be predicates in Chinese.  Sometimes non-native speakers are influenced by their native language and add 是 as copula, even though it is not necessary.  Other examples of sentences, where nouns or pronouns are predicates:

一瓶水多少錢？

外面二十度。

他們中國人嗎？　(In this sentence 他們是中國人嗎？ would put emphasis on 'being Chinese' and increase the tone of doubt.)

Answer (score 0):

'你的生日是什么时候？’seems more natural than '你的生日什么时候？' But it does not mean that '你的生日什么时候’cannot be used in certain situations. Otherwise, it seems to me that '你生日什么时候？' sounds more natural than '你的生日什么时候？’. I do not know exactly the reason for this. It is possible that this relate to the number of characters in one utterance.